# Is there a way to find out each occurrence of a column value in another column from a different dataset?

Tags: python, data-science

I have two datasets: dataset1 & dataset2 (image link provided), which have a common column called `SAX` which is a string object.

```
dataset1=
         SAX
0    glngsyu
1    zicobgm
2    eerptow
3    cqbsynt
4    zvmqben
..       ...
475  rfikekw
476  bnbzvqx
477  rsuhgax
478  ckhloio
479  lbzujtw

480 rows × 2 columns
```

and

```
dataset2 =
    SAX     timestamp
0   hssrlcu 16015
1   ktyuymp 16016
2   xncqmfr 16017
3   aanlmna 16018
4   urvahvo 16019
... ... ...
263455  jeivqzo 279470
263456  bzasxgw 279471
263457  jspqnqv 279472
263458  sxwfchj 279473
263459  gxqnhfr 279474

263460 rows × 2 columns
```

I need to find and print out the timestamps for whenever a value in `SAX` column of `dataset1`  exists in `SAX` column of `dataset2`.
Is there a function/method for accomplishing the above?

Thanks.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question This is a great discussion on why not putting data as images.

Comment: @udkr: If you find my answer helpful, I'd appreciate it if you can mark it as correct (click the tick). Thank you!

Comment: @Albo: yeah buddy , thanks for the help, will click the tick.

Comment: @Albo: hey what if I also want the SAX of dataset 2 whenever there is match between SAX of dataset 1 and 2?

Comment: Add `sax` to the column part for `loc`, like: `df2.loc[df1.sax.apply(lambda x: df2.sax.str.contains(x)).any(), ['timestamp', 'sax']]`

Comment: @Albo: hey sorry for troubling you, but is there a way to check the the occurrence count of each row of SAX(dataset1) in SAX(dataset2).
 Basically the number of time's a value in SAX(dataset1) exists in SAX(dataset2)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create an arbitrary dataset to showcase how it works:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def sax_generator(num):
    return [''.join(chr(x) for x in np.random.randint(97, 97+26, size=4)) for _ in range(num)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(sax_generator(10), columns=['sax'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'sax': sax_generator(10), 'timestamp': range(10)})
```

Let's peek into the data:

```
df1 = 
|    | sax   |
|---:|:------|
|  0 | cvtj  |
|  1 | fmjy  |
|  2 | rjpi  |
|  3 | gwtv  |
|  4 | qhov  |
|  5 | uriu  |
|  6 | kpku  |
|  7 | xkop  |
|  8 | kzoe  |
|  9 | nydj  |

df2 =
|    | sax   |   timestamp |
|---:|:------|------------:|
|  0 | kzoe  |           0 |
|  1 | npyo  |           1 |
|  2 | uriu  |           2 |
|  3 | hodu  |           3 |
|  4 | rdko  |           4 |
|  5 | pspn  |           5 |
|  6 | qnut  |           6 |
|  7 | gtyz  |           7 |
|  8 | gfzs  |           8 |
|  9 | gcel  |           9 |
```

Now ensure we have some matching values in `df2` from `df1`, which we can later check:

```py
df2['sax'][2] = df1['sax'][5]
df2['sax'][0] = df1['sax'][8]
```

Then use:

```py
df2.loc[df1.sax.apply(lambda x: df2.sax.str.contains(x)).any(), 'timestamp']
```

to get:

```
|    |   timestamp |
|---:|------------:|
|  0 |           0 |
|  2 |           2 |
```

With `np.where` [docs here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) you can get the indices back as well:

```
np.where(df1.sax.apply(lambda x: df2.sax.str.contains(x)) == True)
# -> (array([5, 8]), array([2, 0]))
```

Here we can see that `df1` has matching indices `[5, 8]` and `df2` has `[2, 0]`, which is exactly what we enforced with the lines above...
If we have a look at the return of `df1.sax.apply(lambda x: df2.sax.str.contains(x))`, the result above matches exactly the indices (magic...whooo):

```
|    |   0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |   5 |   6 |   7 |   8 |   9 |
|---:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  2 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  3 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  4 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  5 |   0 |   0 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  6 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  7 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  8 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  9 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1: Convert Dataset 2 to a dict using:**
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

```
a_dictionary = df.to_dict['list]
```

**Step2: Use a comparator in a for loop to extract time stamps.**

```
lookup_value = "abcdef" #This can be a list item.

all_keys = []
for key, value in a_dictionary.items():
    if(value == lookup_value):
         all_keys.append(key)

print(all_keys)
```

**Step3: ENJOY!**